# Disable tab as indent character in redactor

Tags: redactor

The default configuration for the tab keys is to indent the paragraph. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I want the tab key to move the cursor to the next input field on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [redactor docs](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/keypress/):

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    tabKey: false
});
```

Comment: Not sure that was there when I was looking but eventually found it in the code.

Comment: For me this sort of works but I still don't get default behavior where it should tab to the next input in the form. How can I make it tab outside redactor? tabKey false for me only disables the creation of the tab in the editor.